# click on div = fadeOut all my html page + unload + load new page + fadeIn

Tags: jquery, html, load, click

I'm trying to do this :

Click on Div
+ FadeOut all my HTML page
+ Unload all html page
+ Load another html page
+ FadeIn on this news page

But after Hours... nothing...
Could'you help me ?

Thanks

```
$('#bt1').click(function() {

        $('html').fadeOut(1000),function() {
               .load('page2.html',function() {
        $(this).fadeIn(1000);
    });
            return false;
});
});
```

Comment: I would think that the problem lies on the fact that you want to unload the previous `HTML` tag. Why not just unload/load the `BODY` tag instead?

Comment: if that would be possible, you'd "unload" the javascript aswell, what you wanna do is unload the content within the body in worst case scenario and reload it with new content

Comment: your javascript is incorrect, see the fadeOut(1000, function(){}); just a head up

Comment: Also, that's not how you use `.load()`. It's not bound to anything. If we were just to fix the syntax, it needs to be `$(html').load(...)`. Also also, what @shadowmonkey said. :)

Answer (score 0):

There were a lot of syntactical problems in the script

Try

```
$(function(){
    $('#bt1').click(function() {
        $('html').fadeOut(1000, function() {
            $(this).load('page2.html', function() {
                $(this).fadeIn(1000);
            });
        });
        return false;
    });
})
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ey4YfzE8CKZSGoFIo6gA?p=preview)